# JAXB Getting error While parsing the XML

Tags: java, parsing, jaxb

While parsing the XML using JAXB am getting error as "javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xffffffff) was found in the element content of the document " . Because in my xml node have some special characters like "TRÊS2115". How to handle this scenario. I need that special character values too.

Comment: provide code that you tried..

Comment: I have used normal JAXB code only

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your input data. The accented character needs to be escaped within the XML file. The code that wrote the file failed to properly encode the character.

Comment: How to escaped in the XML file.. ?

Comment: How did you write the file? Was that with JAXB as well?